# Return NEWSEQUENTIALID() as an output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
     [id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
     [name] [varchar](50) NULL
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_test_id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [id]
GO
```

With an `INSERT` stored procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Insert_test]
    @name as varchar(50),
    @id as uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test(
        name
    )
    VALUES(
        @name
    )
END
```

What is the best way to get the GUID that was just inserted and return it as an output parameter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the Output clause of the Insert statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Insert_test]
    @name as varchar(50),
    @id as uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @returnid table (id uniqueidentifier)

    INSERT INTO test(
        name
    )
    output inserted.id into @returnid
    VALUES(
        @name
    )

    select @id = r.id from @returnid r
END
GO

/* Test the Procedure */
declare @myid uniqueidentifier
exec insert_test 'dummy', @myid output
select @myid
```

Comment: This for sure, is the accpeted answer! I'm using SQL Express 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT @ID = ID FROM Test WHERE Name = @Name
```

(if Name has a Unique constraint)

Comment: "(if Name has a Unique constraint)" There's nothing in the OP to make us think this is a valid assumption and it is unnecessarily restrictive.