# Are there cons to generating GUIDs with a stored procedure using NEWSEQUENTIALID?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My goal is to create a stored procedure that generates new GUIDs using [`NEWSEQUENTIALID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that can then be used when inserting data into a different table in the same database. For example, it would be like the stored procedure described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335148/19104722).

Thus, my question is: are there any negatives, cons, or issues in creating a stored procedure like this and using the GUIDs it generates for insertions into a different table?

For example, would generating GUIDs like this be non-atomic and cause duplicate GUIDs values? Or, for example, is a GUID generated by `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` guaranteed to be unique only for the table it was generated in and thus, inappropriate to reuse in another table?

In other words, even though such an implementation might be a kludge, is it "safe" to generate GUIDs like this?

The only potential concerns I've been able to find are described in the previously linked  `NEWSEQUENTIALID` documentation:

1. > If privacy is a concern, do not use this function. It is possible to guess the value of the next generated GUID and, therefore, access data associated with that GUID.
2. > The UuidCreateSequential function has hardware dependencies. On SQL Server, clusters of sequential values can develop when databases (such as contained databases) are moved to other computers. When using Always On and on SQL Database, clusters of sequential values can develop if the database fails over to a different computer.

And from `UuidCreateSequential` documentation:

3. > In this case, the generated UUID is a valid identifier, and is guaranteed to be unique among all UUIDs generated on the computer. However, the possibility exists that another computer without an ethernet/token ring address generated the identical UUID. Therefore you should never use this UUID to identify an object that is not strictly local to your computer. Computers with ethernet/token ring addresses generate UUIDs that are guaranteed to be globally unique.

The privacy concern described in #1 is negligible for my purposes. I think concern #2 and #3 are negligible, as well, because the table where the GUIDs will be inserted is within the same database that would generate the GUIDs.

Comment: Do you actually need a GUID? Guids lend themselves well to where you can't control the unique key such as where it's generated by external applications or if you have to synchronise with multiple databases, otherwise if the server is the only place keys are generated you would be much better off using an identity integer.

Comment: Yes, I need a GUID for my use case.

Comment: I suggest you implement a proof-of-concept where you actually write and then use your procedure to insert 1 row and to insert many rows - into the same table and into different tables. I can see no clear benefit but your goal is unclear. Your linked "answer" seems to have a very different purpose.

Comment: Whenever I see people sticking hard fast to using newsequentialid is has almost always come to a misunderstanding. Why do you have to use a guid? And why is it ok that the values are no longer hard to guess. In fast they are not just predictable they are known what the next value will be. Using newsequentialid has almost all of the downsides of a true guid and none of the advantages.

Comment: My ultimate goal is for the stored procedure to produce an arbitrary amount of GUIDs generated with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. The amount generated would be specified by a parameter of the stored procedure. The linked answer was an example that looked very similar to the proof on concept I had written, but the example provided [David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221843/19104722) is essentially what I'm looking for. However, I apologize that the linked answer is not completely in alignment. Thus, my question is not if this is possible or not, but if generating them like this is "safe".

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "safe". As long as there is not a failover cluster and the database never gets restored to another server it will generate unique values. But again...most of the time "requiring" unique values across the entire database is not needed.

Comment: I recognize the word "safe" is very unspecific, but I think you may be getting at what I'm trying to figure out. Under average circumstances - will generating GUIDs like this ever result in non-unique values being produced or a similar erroneous situation? 
As for why I need to use a sequential GUID - the column of the table where the GUIDs are inserted into has a clustered index and because this insertion is atypical because newsequentialid can't be used as normal (i.e., automatically filled by the `DEFAULT` constraint)

Comment: The documentation you posted answers that question. If you want further confirmation try this one. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224783/is-newsequentialid-unique-within-a-database-for-many-tables

Comment: Maybe you could use a bigint identity in the database and then just add zeros for the rest of your "guid" outside of the database.  That would give you CPU word-sized values in the database.  I assume you don't need more than 2^64 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be fine.  But you can simplify the generating procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GenerateNewSequentalId  @id as uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    declare @returnid table (id uniqueidentifier);
    declare @test table(id uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid());
    INSERT INTO @test 
    output inserted.id into @returnid
    default values;

    select @id = r.id from @returnid r;
END
GO

/* Test the Procedure */
declare @myid uniqueidentifier
exec GenerateNewSequentalId @myid output
select @myid
```